# ZXING example app not working

Tags: android, zxing

I followed instructions from the official zxing website and created an application using the following code. I tried to send the signed `.apk` file to my Samsung GSII for testing. The program stopped immediately after I clicked on the application's icon.

I am really sorry for my poor description and wordings.
Instead of using the embedded method,I finally used the IntentIntegrator for the program, as embedded one is too hard for me to understand.

Now I am facing another issue. I have wrote an onClick Method with the following statements:

```
public void Button1(View view){
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.initiateScan();
EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
editText2.setText(a);
}
```

How can I change the code so that it waits until the initiateScan() method finished before the setText() method operate? Actually I would like to use the returned result from initiateScan() as a condition.

Thanks again!

Comment: Post the logcat.Without that its only guesswork.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I would like to use zxing to read the qrcode..collec the id,and retreieve the correspondng info from database.aftetwards, display those info on the mobile screen...

Answer (score 0):

You don't wait for `initiateScan()` to finish. This function invokes the Barcode Scanner application. You wait for the result instead by implementing `onActivityResult()` in your app.  This is documented in the [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent) and in the javadoc. Did you read any of that, at all?

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to perform other actions within the onActivityResult() method now.Seems is not working.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but it's not anything to do with the library.